# cifs mount gone after reboot laptop

Tags: networking, dns, cifs

I've got a cifs share to a laptop mounted in /etc/fstab. This is ubuntu 20.4.

```
//lt2345/share /mnt/test/lt12345 cifs _netdev,noserverino,nocase,rw,cred=/etc/cifspasswd,vers=3.11 0 0
```

it works fine until the laptop is rebooted. Then the mount is gone.

It turns out that the ip address of the laptop changes and the linux machine still has the old ip address. Only

```
 sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

then umount and mount -a and it works again

But I dont want to manually flush dns and remount every time the laptop is started of course.
How can we fix that a CIFS mount stays "connected" even after the ip address changes?

It seems that a common solution is to create a timer/cronjob that does exactly that, flush cache, umount and mount but I cant believe there is no software handled automatic solution.

Comment: When the IP address changes, you're a different computer. You could adjust the DHCP server (where you get your IP address) to always assign the same IP address to your MAC address.

Comment: this is in a realm where clients connect over VPN, I cant control that